# Usage of the Google's directions API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google's directions API to find the distance between two addresses. The following is the URL I use for the call.

```
string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin + 
"&destination=" 
+ destination + "&key=" + key;
The following is part of the response I got.
legs:[ 
{ 
  distance:{ 
  text:13.4 mi,
  value:21608
},
```

The text has the correct distance as 13.4 miles. I am not sure what the value:21608 represents. I thought it was in feet or yards, but neither turns out to be correct.

Comment: Well, it's all [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=fr#UnitSystems). Usually takes longer to open a question here than to do a quick search in the official docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Text is value just floored from decimal.
Value is in meters.


According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Legs), `distance.value` is in meters ("`value` indicates the distance in meters").